# Mac OS focus on right-click

Tags: macos, mouse, window-focus

Is there any way to have Mac OS focus a window that I right-click on? It happens to me quite frequently that I right-click on something, choose "rename" or "create file" or what have you, need to type the filename and the keyboard input goes to another window, because Mac OS appears to switch focus only on a left-click.

Comment: Concrete example: Right-click on a background Pages document, select *Create paragraph style from selection* (a sheet dialog will appear) and you cannot start typing.

Comment: Another common case for me is to create a new tab in Safari, when out of focus. The tab gets created but you can't type the URL because you are still out of focus. This seems to be an issue (bug?) that can be fixed with the next Mac OS X Release... But what can be the side effects of this issue being fixed? Is it really an issue or deliberate feature?

Comment: Yes, that is the kind of thing that is bugging me so much. I take it this means that there is no solution?

Comment: 9 years and still a problem :(

Comment: The issue is mainly when opening new Tab in Chrome by right clicking and then the cursor appears. When we start typing, it goes to the other window. Its definitely a bug. How can it open new tab, but can't type?

Answer (score 5):

Having the same problem as OP, I found a solution today:

[BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai/) (45 days of free trial, licenses from $6.50) can assign multiple actions to a gesture.

[image: Image showing gesture config]

1. Depending on your mouse setup, choose a trigger. I use a MagicMouse, so I chose '1 Finger Tap Right'.
2. Choose 'Activate/Bring to Front Window Under Cursor'
3. 'Click Add Additional Action'
4. Choose 'Right Click'

Now BetterTouchTool will first activate the window under cursor, then dispatch a right click to it. Seems to work just fine on the Applications I tested it on.

Comment: unfortunately BTT does not support USB mouse right click yet :( https://github.com/folivoraAI/BetterTouchTool/issues/1219

Comment: This works for me using a wireless mouse with a USB receiver. Thanks!

Comment: Coming back to this, I realized what I really wanted from macOS was **focus follows mouse**. I recommend https://github.com/sbmpost/AutoRaise which has been working well for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try control-clicking. What happens? (Different apps behave differently with this--Finder being a notable exception.)

Comment: It *somewhat* works for me. The window gets focus, and the context menu opens, but I cannot release the mouse button or the context menu will close; so I have to keep it pressed down, and release over the desired menu entry to select it. But other than that, it works quite well.

Comment: That seems to behave a bit too erratically per app (and sometimes even inside the same app) to be useful.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to have focus follow right-click across all apps on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [MondoMouse](http://www.atomicbird.com/mondomouse/) ($14.95, trial available), which supports Focus Follows Mouse.

Or from [OS X: Point-to-Focus?](http://jeremy.zawodny.com/blog/archives/000149.html)

> To enable [sloppy focus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focus_%28computing%29#Sloppy_focus) do:
>
> for just Terminal windows:
>
> ```
> % defaults write com.apple.Terminal FocusFollowsMouse
> ```
>
> -string YES
>
> for X11 windows:
>
> ```
> % defaults write com.apple.x11 wm_ffm true
> ```
>
> for most other Mac apps:
>
> ```
> use Codetek Virtual Desktop
> ```

Comment: Close, but "focus follows pointer" is a bit too much for what I need. What I'm looking for is still click-to-focus, but not just on left-click, also on right (and middle) click.

Comment: All too often I find myself typing after right clicking another window and see that nothing is typed in the window I right clicked on, because it did not receive focus on the right click. Also I think that it's too much that a window gets the focus just by hovering over it with the pointer.